# Finding item in dictionary ignoring key case

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def language_Selection(lang):
    switcher = {
        "Telugu" || "TELUGU"||"telugu": 'te',
        "Hindi"||"HINDI"||"hindi": 'hi',
        "Tamil"||"TAMIL"||"tamil": 'ta',
    }
    return switcher.get(lang,"Invalid languge of selection")
```

here i need to use the logical operator at the switch statement in python

Comment: Python doesn't have a `switch` statement — that's a dictionary.

Comment: `switcher` is not a valid dictionary

Comment: `"Telugu" || "TELUGU"||"telugu"` is not valid Python. Spending some time with a Python tutorial could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to lowercase and use keys in lowercase:

```
def language_Selection(lang):
    switcher = {
        "telugu" : 'te',
        "hindi": 'hi',
        "tamil": 'ta',
    }
    return switcher.get(lang.lower(),"Invalid languge of selection")

# ta
print(language_Selection(lang='TaMiL'))
```